# Addin Ribbon not visible in powerpoint

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, office-interop, powerpoint-automation

I have created a addin ribbon in visual studio interop power point. But now 
I am not able to see the addin ribbon when i run my project can someone suggest what the problem is. I do not even get debugger within this code that i tried  where it loads the ribbon

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sometimes happens to me in ms word.. you need to save it , build the solution and rebuild it and then it becomes visible